# Xcode error(I think)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am quite a noob at Xcode and I can't find the reason why when I run my app it freezes and says

> "Thread 1 breakpoint 1.1" on line 32.

When running the app I get no errors`(except 1 minor one on line 111).`

My entire `.m` file(couldn't get code inserted successfully so I just used pastebin): 
[enter link description here](http://pastebin.com/pLicGJny)

P.S. When I've removed the score counter(SKLabel) it works just fine.

If you need to see any other of my `.m` or `.h` files just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app didn't freeze, the debugger simply stopped at a breakpoint. Breakpoints are used to stop the program during execution so that you can examine variable values or step through the code a line at a time. Just click the 'continue' button (it's the one that looks like a right-facing triangle with a line to its left) to continue on. Or delete the breakpoint and run the program again.

[image: continue button]